# Hide the active indent guide

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spywhere.guides

With the following settings:

```
"guides.enabled": false,
"editor.renderIndentGuides": false,
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorIndentGuide.background": "#fff0",
    "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#fff0"
}
```

Yet, the **active** indent guide is still visible.

Is this a bug in VS Code?

**edit:** Disabling the extension does nothing.

Comment: I am not using the extension you mentioned, and `"editor.renderIndentGuides": false` disables indent guides. Are you sure is not a problem with another extension?

Comment: @Amade Does it disable the **active** indent guide? The one that's darker than the others.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Here's what I see with enabled indent guides: https://ibb.co/cAZjAK and this with disabled: https://ibb.co/bQGgqK

Comment: @Amade Put your cursor on a line that is indented twice (or more). You should see the "active" indent guide, unless you have extensions or settings that changes that.

Comment: ok, I see now what you mean. They are not visible at all in the theme I'm using (Cobalt2). But there is a setting `editor.highlightActiveIndentGuide` which deactivates active indents (at least in version `1.26.1` which I am using). Tested this with one of the 'default' themes, and it works. If the setting still doesn't work for you, just solve it via colors as described here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48401.

Comment: @Amade That seems like the right setting, but it has no effect. I even tried reloading the window. I'm also using `v1.26.1`. As I said above, I've already tried changing the color, too.

Comment: What happens if you disable all extensions? There is a command for this: `Extensions: Disable All Installed Extensions for this Workspace`. Also, maybe you have the `editor.highlightActiveIndentGuide` setting set to `true` for your *workspace*?